# How to get Twitter follower count for more than 100 usernames in Google Sheets?

Tags: javascript, twitter, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I don't know my JavaScript. So I am using someone else's:

```
var CONSUMER_KEY = 'xxxx'; // Register your app with Twitter.
var CONSUMER_SECRET = 'xxxx'; // Register your app with Twitter.

function getTwitterUserFollowers(id) {
    // Encode consumer key and secret
    var tokenUrl = "https://api.twitter.com/oauth2/token";
    var tokenCredential = Utilities.base64EncodeWebSafe(
        CONSUMER_KEY + ":" + CONSUMER_SECRET);

    //  Obtain a bearer token with HTTP POST request
    var tokenOptions = {
        headers: {
            Authorization: "Basic " + tokenCredential,
            "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8" 
        },
        method: "post",
        payload: "grant_type=client_credentials"
    };

    var responseToken = UrlFetchApp.fetch(tokenUrl, tokenOptions);
    var parsedToken = JSON.parse(responseToken);
    var token = parsedToken.access_token;

    // Authenticate Twitter API requests with the bearer token
    var apiUrl = 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/users/show.json?screen_name='+id;
    var apiOptions = {
        headers: {
            Authorization: 'Bearer ' + token
        },
        "method": "get"
    };

    var responseApi = UrlFetchApp.fetch(apiUrl, apiOptions);

    var result = "";

    if (responseApi.getResponseCode() == 200) {
        // Parse the JSON encoded Twitter API response
        var tweets = JSON.parse(responseApi.getContentText());
        return tweets.followers_count
    }

    Logger.log(result);
}
```

source: http://sarahmarshall.io/post/70812214349/how-to-add-twitter-follower-counts-to-a-google

Sarah Marshall provides a pretty awesome how-to on using a Google Sheets script with the Twitter API to get follower counts for a list of Twitter user names. But it times out after about 100 user names:

> `Service invoked too many times for one day: urlfetch. (line 21, file "Code")`

I'm wondering how I can get around the rate limit, or account for it, and return follower counts for more than 100 user names. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function you are using does too many things: it both obtains a token and uses it to retrieve followers. So, if you are invoking it 100 times, you obtain a token 100 times (and notably, time out on the line obtaining it); but you need it *once*. You should store the token somewhere, e.g., in the spreadsheet itself since you already have your private data in the script associated with it. Example:

```
function getToken() {
    //  Obtain a bearer token with HTTP POST request
    var tokenOptions = {
        headers: {
            Authorization: "Basic " + tokenCredential,
            "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8"
        },
        method: "post",
        payload: "grant_type=client_credentials"
    };

    var responseToken = UrlFetchApp.fetch(tokenUrl, tokenOptions);
    var parsedToken = JSON.parse(responseToken);
    var token = parsedToken.access_token;
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('SheetWithToken').getRange('A1').setValue(token);
}
```

The last line stores the token string in cell A1 of the sheet named SheetWithToken. You'd invoke this function once, manually from the Script Editor.

The following function does the rest: it can be invoked as a custom function `=getFollowers(A2)` from the spreadsheet. Custom functions, like other spreadsheet functions, are re-evaluated only when the parameter changes. Thus, if the column with IDs (say, A) has a thousand of entries, you can paste the custom function gradually, for a handful at once.

```
function getFollowers(id) {
    // Authenticate Twitter API requests with the bearer token
    var token = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('SheetWithToken').getRange('A1').getValue();
    var apiUrl = 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/users/show.json?screen_name='+id;
    var apiOptions = {
        headers: {
            Authorization: 'Bearer ' + token
        },
        "method": "get"
    };

    var responseApi = UrlFetchApp.fetch(apiUrl, apiOptions);
    var result = "";
    if (responseApi.getResponseCode() == 200) {
        // Parse the JSON encoded Twitter API response
        var tweets = JSON.parse(responseApi.getContentText());
        return tweets.followers_count
    }
}
```

You could even hardcode your access token into the second function, instead of fetching it from the spreadsheet. Twitter's  tokens do not expire.

---

Another thing to consider is to recast the function `getFollowers` so that it accepts an array of IDs and loops through them, returning an array of follower counts. I don't think this would help, though: you would still have to worry about rate-limit on Twitter side, and at the same time  be limited to 30 second execution time limit for custom functions.